# Jenkins & Github & NodeJS & Docker issue with building from script

Tags: node.js, jenkins, github

Everything works perfect, unless one thing. I have a deploy script called deploy.sh explained below. I am running the build inside a node docker container and I run this script at the end of the build. The deploy script goes well until the production-build.sh. Sometimes it fails with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "bin/docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
 File "compose/cli/main.py", line 71, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 127, in perform_command
 File "compose/cli/main.py", line 282, in build
 File "compose/project.py", line 373, in build
 File "compose/service.py", line 1027, in build
 File "site-packages/docker/api/build.py", line 154, in build
 File "site-packages/docker/utils/build.py", line 31, in tar
 File "site-packages/docker/utils/build.py", line 162, in create_archive
 File "tarfile.py", line 1803, in gettarinfo
 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'/home/application/api/jenkins-data/logs/sse-events/job'
[26943] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

It doesn't happen all the time. For example the deploy was successful after pushing to master directly and this error appeared when merged from a pull request (by accepting the merge).

Has anyone any idea where could it come from ?

Deploy.sh file

```
ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@application.com <<EOF
 echo '**** Change directory to project...'
 cd /home/application/api
 echo '**** Getting latest changes from git repo...'
 git pull
 echo '**** Installing node modules...'
 npm install --production
 bash -c "./bash/production-build.sh"
 bash -c "./bash/production-api-up.sh"
 exit
EOF
```

Jenkins file

```
#!groovy

pipeline {
agent {
    docker {
        image 'node:carbon'
        args '-v /root/.ssh:/root/.ssh'
    }
}
stages {
    stage('Prepare') {
        steps {
            sh 'npm install'
            sh 'npm install -g typescript && npm install -g tslint'
        }
    }
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            sh 'tsc'
        }
    }
    stage('Lint') {
        steps {
            sh 'npm run lint'
        }
    }
    stage('Unit Test') {
        steps {
            sh 'npm run test'
        }
    }
    stage('Deploy') {
        steps {
            sh '/var/jenkins_home/api/bash/deploy.sh'
        }
    }
}
}
```

EDIT: Production-build.sh script

```
#!/bin/bash

# API & MongoDB services
echo '**** Restarting api...'
bash -c "docker-compose -f docker-compose.production.yaml build"
```

EDIT 2:

I have pushed directly to master and the deploy worked. I merged a pull request and it failed right there. Afterwards tried a direct push from terminal again and it worked (again)!

Comment: Can you provide the `production-build.sh` script? It's hard to understand without the code.